# Constructing idele from a rational number.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am a novice to concept of idele, despite the fact that I have gone through all its expositions in standard literature.  Excusing my ignorance, suppose I take $q=396000$. Does it mean that the idele $q=(1,32,9,125,11,1,1,1,...)$ for $q=396000= 32\cdot 9\cdot 125\cdot 11$? Because according to the idele-ideal recipe, $$(396000)=\Pi_{vfinite}\;p_v^{ord_v(a_v)}=p_2^{ord_2(32)}\cdot p_3^{ord_3(9)}\cdot p_5^{ord_5(125)}\cdot p_7^{ord_7(1)}\cdot p_{11}^{ord_{11}(11)},$$

because $q=396000=2^5\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^0\cdot 11^1$. Have I given the correct expression for the homomorphism from ideles to ideals ? Please help.

Comment: I made a mistake. The idele must be q=(396000,396000,396000,....) by diagonal embedding. And all orders should be for 396000 wrt different p. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not right.  The ideles are a subset of the infinite product $\prod_p \mathbb Q_p \times \mathbb R$.  The way you embed $\mathbb Q^\times$ inside the ideles corresponds to the diagonal embedding, i.e., take the embedding of $\mathbb Q^\times$ into each $\mathbb Q_p^\times$ and $\mathbb R^\times$.  Thus, for any (nonzero) rational number $a$, the embedding looks like
$$ a \mapsto (a, a, a, \ldots).$$